# velocity template resource not found exception

Tags: java, servlets, velocity

> Exception occurred:
>   org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to
>   find resource 'ResourceLoader1.vm'

I am having ResourceLoader1.vm in /WEB-INF/templates, I stuck up with this please help me.

```
            Properties props = new Properties();  
            props.put("file.resource.loader.path", "/WEB-INF/templates");
            Velocity.init(props);
            VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
            context.put("greetings", "Many Happy returns");
            context.put("name", "Joseph");
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("ResourceLoader1.vm");
            template.merge(context, writer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put .vm templates relative to the CLASSPATH.  A better choice would be to put the /templates directory under WEB-INF/classes, lose the props, and fetch it like this:

```
Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("templates/ResourceLoader1.vm");
```

Comment: I tried but there is no classes directory under WEB-INF in eclipse ,I am running in Eclipse IDE, but there is only classes directory available under build.So I put templates/ResourceLoader1.vm under build/classes.Please help me to understand if I am wrong.

Comment: Tell Eclipse to copy your /templates directory and its contents into the WEB-INF/classes when it creates your WAR file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're using Velocity in a web application. For this, you'd be better off using the [VelocityViewServlet](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/view.html) that's specifically designed for this kind of usage.

The `FileResourceLoader` that's used with your configuration has no knowledge of the webserver and contexts and stuff, so the way you've configured it, it would look for a `WEB-INF` folder at the **root of the filesystem** your application server is running at.